# 2012 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2012 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Sadly attempting to nominate myself again did not find a coding loophole and crash your entire system(@community)

Comment: Their has been some confusion, this is for two **new** moderators. Markrages, Kevin Vermeer and myself will be continuing to moderate with them.

Comment: It seems you can only nominate yourself, not others?  Most nominations in real life don't work that way, although of course someone nominated by another would have to accept the nomination before they are fully nominated within the system.

Comment: @OlinLathrop they attempted the nominating others and the user has to accept it and such first, this is much cleaner. Are you going to get brave enough to throw yourself in the fire?

Comment: @Kortuk: No, I wouldn't make a good moderator, but I might suggest others run for moderator by nominating them if that were possible. Seeing a nomination might give someone the courage to run that would otherwise not nominate themselves. Also, I can see people being reluctant to nominate themselves since it feels too much like tooting your own horn. By not allowing second party nominations I think you get a limited slate, self-selected for not always the best reasons.

Comment: @Kortuk: I think it would be good if you de-mystify the whole process at bit. I read the page linked to above, but it leaves out a lot of stuff. For example, how often are elections? What is the term? Why are we only adding moderators now? Who/what decides how many moderators there are? Why does it seem like 1 year plus a couple months since the last election? Is this deliberate or did someone just forget? There is a lot us peons are wondering that doesn't seem to be explained anywhere.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Talk to someone in chat about it, I can help by superpinging them so you can talk to them(you just have to get chat working). You could make a great moderator with one caveat, being nice in your comments. I know it can be frustrating to deal with people that seem to just ignore basic formatting rules and dont take the time, but if you could make progress on that you already do most of the rest of the work.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, your answers are here.

Comment: @Kortuk: I don't agree that always being nice is the best approach, which is why you wouldn't want me as a moderator.  Sometimes people are arrogant jerks and dump slop on us.  They should be bluntly sent off, not get a welcome reception or have people fix it for them.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, All I ask is when someone is new you start by informing them we are not like other sites, many forums accept that. It is a bad habit but one they were taught. Instead let them know our site is different and that until quality is improved the question will remained closed. Easy as pie. At this point you assume they are new and just dont know better, if they continue to dump crap instead of correcting and improving, we suspend, but often they either correct or never return. Most of the time it is not a real registered account and they leave the computer and loose the account.

Answer (score 3):

Quick requested Q&A.

> how often are elections?

When load increases enough to require new moderators or when a current moderator has to reduce their time to moderate and requests it.

> What is the term?

Life, or until we choose to retire. Yes, You are stuck with me for a while.

> Why are we only adding moderators now?

A current moderator is having to reduce time on the site.

> Who/what decides how many moderators there are?

The stack-exchange team. There is a team of community managers whom make calls like this, they are also full time employees whom act as a constant group to support moderators whom have questions or need guidance. We let them know if we are having issue and they make the decision.

> Why does it seem like 1 year plus a couple months since the last election?

That sounds like about how long it has been, forgive me for not looking it up to be sure. The time since last election does not have any bearing on this election.

> Is this deliberate or did someone just forget?

I am betting the reasoning is now clear from the previous questions. No, the community managers have been communicating with us for a while now and this is only a surprise to the site, was hard to stay quiet knowing all the coming excitement.

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up.  I am surprised moderators leave Stack Exchange by being carried out feet first though.  I don't mean this in any way as a comment on you, I'd vote for you again, but a fixed term just sounds sensible.  If a community likes a moderator, they can re-elect him.  People change, and even the site may evolve a bit over time so that a particular moderator is not a good fit anymore.

Comment: @OlinLathrop we do have oversight from the same community managers, so far the evolution of the community has not been an issue to my knowledge on any site. There is never only a single moderator, if one moderator feels a way but the others disagree our little community rules.

Comment: Thanks for all this info. I thought I hung around the site enough to know stuff like this, but you mention a lot of things I wasn't aware of. Another question you might edit into what is already there: How many of the 4 candidates will become new moderators?